# Are there instances when Brahma used the Brahmastra?

Tags: brahma, weapon

Siva uses the Pashupatasstra as his ultimate weapon and Vishnu the Vaishnavastra or Narayanastra.

Brahma is not depicted as engaging in war that frequently - but is he known to have used his own weapon, the Brahmastra?